# Why this test fails?

Tags: python

After adding a new unit test I started to get failures in unrelated test run after the new test. I could not understand why.

I have simplified the case to the code below. I still do not understand what is going on. I am surprised that commenting out seemingly unrelated lines of code affects the result: **removing the call to `isinstance` in `Block.__init__` changes the result of `isinstance(blk, AddonDefault)` in `test_addons`**.

```
import abc

class Addon:
    pass

class AddonDefault(Addon, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        isinstance(self, CBlock)

class CBlock(Block, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if issubclass(cls, Addon):
            raise TypeError("Do not mix Addons and CBlocks!")
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)

class FBlock(CBlock):
    pass

def test_addons():
    try:
        class CBlockWithAddon(CBlock, AddonDefault):
            pass
    except TypeError:
        pass

    blk = FBlock()
    assert not isinstance(blk, AddonDefault), "TEST FAIL"
    print("OK")

test_addons()
```

When I run `python3 test.py` I get the TEST FAIL exception. But `FBlock` is derived from `CBlock` which is derived from `Block`. How can it be an instance of `AddonDefault`?

---

UPDATE: I'd like to emphasize that the only purpose of the posted code is to demonstrate the behaviour I cannot understand. It was created by reducing a much larger program as much as I was able to. During this process any logic it had before was lost, so please take it as it is and focus on the question why it gives an apparantly incorrect answer.

Comment: Did you try to debug your `__init_subclass__`?

Comment: @taras One of the original unit tests was to verify that the `__init__subclass__` is doing its job.

Comment: You may wanna read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: `isinstance(self, CBlock)`?

Comment: @stefan Yes. That line does nothing in theory (no assignment). But if you remove it, it changes the outcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer, but some hints.

It seems that `CBlockWithAddon` is still seen as a subclass of `AddonDefault`. E.g. add two print statements to your `test_addons()`:

```
def test_addons():
    print(AddonDefault.__subclasses__())
    try:
        class CBlockWithAddon(CBlock, AddonDefault):
            pass
    except TypeError:
        pass

    print(AddonDefault.__subclasses__())
    blk = FBlock()
    assert not isinstance(blk, AddonDefault), "TEST FAIL"
    print("OK")
```

results in

```
[]
[<class '__main__.test_addons.<locals>.CBlockWithAddon'>]
...
AssertionError: TEST FAIL
```

`_py_abc` [tests for this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/472f37ab9a33050d7d50d1ebe33ba324a51c52c2/Lib/_py_abc.py#L140):

```
    # Check if it's a subclass of a subclass (recursive)
    for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
        if issubclass(subclass, scls):
            cls._abc_cache.add(subclass)
            return True
```

This will return True when `cls=AddonDefault`, `subclass=FBlock` and `scls=CBlockWithAddon`.

So it seems two things are going wrong:

- The improperly created CBlockWithAddon is still seen as a subclass of AddonDefault.
- But CBlockWithAddon is somehow created such that it seems to be a superclass of FBlock.

Perhaps the broken CBlockWithAddon is effectively identical to CBlock, and is therefore a superclass of FBlock.

This is enough for me now. Maybe it helps your investigation.

(I had to use `import _py_abc as abc` for this analysis. It doesn't seem to matter.)

---

Edit1: My hunch about `CBlockWithAddon` resembling its superclass `CBlock` seems correct:

```py
CBWA = AddonDefault.__subclasses__()[0]
print(CBWA)
print(CBWA.__dict__.keys())
print(CBlock.__dict__.keys())
print(CBWA._abc_cache is CBlock._abc_cache)
```

gives

```
<class '__main__.test_addons.<locals>.CBlockWithAddon'>
dict_keys(['__module__', '__doc__'])
dict_keys(['__module__', '__init_subclass__', '__doc__', '__abstractmethods__', '_abc_registry', '_abc_cache', '_abc_negative_cache', '_abc_negative_cache_version'])
True
```

So `CBlockWithAddon` is not properly created, e.g. its cache registry is not properly set. So accessing those attributes will access those of the (first) super class, in this case `CBlock`. The not-so dummy `isinstance(self, CBlock)` will populate the cache when `blk` is created, because `FBlock` is indeed a subclass of `CBlock`. This cache is then incorrectly reused when `isinstance(blk, AddonDefault)` is called.

I think this answers the question as is. Now the next question would be: why does `CBlockWithAddon` become a subclass of `CBlock` when it was never properly defined?

---

Edit2: Simpler Proof of Concept.

```py
from abc import ABCMeta

class Animal(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

class Plant(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        assert not issubclass(cls, Animal), "Plants cannot be Animals"

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

try:
    class Triffid(Animal, Plant):
        pass
except Exception:
    pass

print("Dog is Animal?", issubclass(Dog, Animal))
print("Dog is Plant?", issubclass(Dog, Plant))
```

will result in

```
Dog is Animal? True
Dog is Plant? True
```

Note that changing the order of the print statements will result in

```
Dog is Plant? False
Dog is Animal? False
```

Comment: Thank you for the investigative work. I think the issue is a bug and should be reported. If you don't intend to do so, I will. May I then use your Animal/Plant example?

Comment: Seems like a bug indeed. Class creation should either work or not work, not leave the system in such an ambiguous state. Go ahead and report it; it would make more sense if you do it. I was merely intrigued by this puzzle and it gave me some insight in abstract base classes and `__init_subclass__`. (Currently refactoring code so old that `__new__` wasn't around.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I want to supplement that in `__init_subclass__` phase, the class is already created, you can even assign it to a global variable and later use it as a normal class, so it's up to `abc` to garantee that `_abc_cache` is of the class's own rather than of a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making sub classes abstract instead of the base classes?
Is there some kind of logic behind this?

If you move abstraction one layer up it works as intended otherwise you mix type and abc metaclasses:

```
import abc

class Addon(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class AddonDefault(Addon):
    pass

class Block(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        isinstance(self, CBlock)

class CBlock(Block):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if issubclass(cls, Addon):
            raise TypeError("Do not mix Addons and CBlocks!")
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)

class FBlock(CBlock):
    pass

def test_addons():
    try:
        class CBlockWithAddon(CBlock, AddonDefault):
            pass
    except TypeError:
        pass

    blk = FBlock()
    assert not isinstance(blk, AddonDefault), "TEST FAIL"
    print("OK")

test_addons()
```

Comment: The posted code has only one purpose - to make the problem easily reproducible. Can you explain why changing the "abstractness" of classes affects the test whether `FBlock` inherits from `AddonDefault`?